# parametrized a sikuli script via GUI input

Tags: sikuli

I would like to create a GUI in python to allow me to more conveniently initialize values of my sikuli script.

I would like to know where is the best way to add my GUI code. It seems in the sikuli script itself is not a valid option, as `import Tkinter` leads to ImportError: No module named Tkinter.

Awaiting for your suggestions, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer here : https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/263314

Basically, Tkinter relies to much on C, while sikuli relies on java thus making both kind of incompatible.

Using JPython instead of Tkinter solved my problem.